# Android MediaPlayer переключение на следующий трек

Tags: java, android, массивы

Делаю музыкальный проигрыватель. Столкнулся с проблемой переключением на следующий трек содержащийся в массиве sounds[]. Как передать currentSound индекс новой записи?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer currentSound;
int[] sounds;
int[] soundsNames;
int currentIndex = 0;
int currentNameIndex = 0;
private static String TAG = "LOGGIN";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sounds = new int[] {R.raw.rain, R.raw.sea, R.raw.birds};
    soundsNames = new int[] {R.string.soundNameRain,
                             R.string.soundNameSea,
                             R.string.soundNameBirds};

    currentSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[currentIndex]);

    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    Button prevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playStopButton);
    final TextView playNow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playingNow);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.nextButton:
                    if (currentNameIndex<soundsNames.length - 1){currentNameIndex++;}
                    else currentNameIndex = 0;
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(currentNameIndex));
                    playNow.setText(soundsNames[currentNameIndex]);

                    if (currentIndex<sounds.length-1){currentIndex++;}
                    else currentIndex = 0;
                    Log.i(TAG, "currentIndex: " + String.valueOf(currentIndex));
                    currentSound.reset();


                    break;

                case R.id.prevButton:
                    if (currentNameIndex>0){currentNameIndex--;}
                    else currentNameIndex = soundsNames.length - 1;
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(currentNameIndex));
                    playNow.setText(soundsNames[currentNameIndex]);

                    if (currentIndex>0){currentIndex--;}
                    else currentIndex = sounds.length-1;
                    Log.i(TAG, "currentIndex: " + String.valueOf(currentIndex));
                    currentSound.reset();

                    break;

                case R.id.playStopButton:
                    if(currentSound.isPlaying()){
                        currentSound.pause();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stop");
                    }
                    else{
                        currentSound.start();
                        currentSound.setLooping(true);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Starting + Looping");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

playNow.setText(soundsNames[currentNameIndex]);
Log.i(TAG, "App ready");
nextButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
prevButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
playButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С медиаплеером давно не работал. но кажется вот так.

```
 if (currentSound.isPlaying()) {
           currentSound.stop();
           currentSound.release();
                    currentSound = null;
    }
    currentSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[currentIndex]);
    currentSound.prepare();
    currentSound.start();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, однако на будущее если кто столкнется с подобной проблемой  нужно создавать `Media Player` с конкретным классом, в примере `MainActivity.this`